# How do I get my if loop to stop ignoring the position 1?

Tags: c#, arrays

Im trying to create an if loop that writes out the numbers at odd (non-even) positions in an array, which it does on every position except 1. I assume this is because the modulus rounds down the 0.5 to 0. I have resorted to just writing it out but am thinking that there must be a better way.

```
int[] num = new int[10];
Random rand = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < num.Length; i++)
{
    num[i] = rand.Next(1, 50);
}
for (int i=0; i < num.Length;i++)
{
    Console.Write(" " + num[i] + " ");
}
for (int i = 0; i < num.Length; ++i)
{
    if (i%2 != 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(" " + num[i]);
    }
}
```

I tried having the modulus operation as a seperate double to see if that would make it register the 0.5 but it didn't make a difference. I also added a specific "OR" variable in the if loop for i = 1 but for some reason that didn't work either.

[This is the result I get from the code above:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSKyT.png)

Comment: It's really unclear to me what you want to achieve... but `if (i % 2 != 0)` will definitely execute the body of the `if` statement when `i` is 1. If you don't believe it will, please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates that. (No need for an array - just print `i` in the body of the `if` statement.) Here's an example which shows it working fine: https://gist.github.com/jskeet/24789bf488877f62dfe4031787d1343e

Comment: "I assume this is because the modulus rounds down the 0.5 to 0" - there is no division here, and no 0.5 here to round, so... I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: @JonSkeet I provided a screenshot in the OP with the result I get. My goal is to get it to print num[1], num[3], num[5] etc. but as you can see it jumps right to 31, which as far as I know is num[3]. Your example seems to work though, do you know why it doesn't do the same for mine?

Comment: Your first position is written at the end of the first line. Because of Console.Write stays on the same line. You need a CR before entering the next loop.

Comment: Note that if you'd provided the [mcve] *including output* to start with, I suspect we'd have been able to spot the problem earlier. That's worth remembering for future questions.

Comment: Please add the mentioned results as text, not as an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing is that the loop, which shows only the odd numbers, starts at the end of the first line.

If you count the numbers on the first line.. you count 11 (instead of 10).

That's because the Console.Write stays on the same line for the next write. You need to insert a CR there.

```
int[] num = new int[10];
Random rand = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < num.Length; i++)
{
    num[i] = rand.Next(1, 50);
}
for (int i=0; i < num.Length;i++)
{
    Console.Write(" " + num[i] + " ");
}

// insert a linebreak here. So the next output starts
// on a new line.
Console.WriteLine();

for (int i = 0; i < num.Length; ++i)
{
    if (i%2 != 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(" " + num[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code is not ignoring position one. You can see this by writing the indices of the rows it is writing:

```cs
    if (i % 2 != 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{i} {num[i]}");
    }
```

The problem is not what you think it is, and we can't answer something that is based on an incorrect premise (i.e. that it is misbehaving, when it isn't).

Comment: More specifically I am trying to write out num[1], num[3], num[5], etc but I can't get it to write out the num [1], it just jumps right to num[3]. My question is then why does this happen? And can I get it to write out num[1] without telling it to seperately? I'm sorry if I'm unclear, I'm new to programming and don't really know how things tie together.

Comment: No it's not jumps to num[3]. num[1] is showing in the end of line where you shows all number.

Answer (score 0):

The first item in the array is printing on the top line. The '2' at the end of the first line is what you're expecting to be as the first new line, but your Console.WriteLine statement only writes a new line AFTER it prints the given string. You can add a console.writeline("") before the last loop and it'll work how you expect.